# NATS on K8s expose

Tags: kubernetes, nats.io, nats-jetstream

I am new to NATS and kubernetics technologies. I watched the full ["TechWorld with Nana" kubernetics tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X48VuDVv0do&t=3300s&ab_channel=TechWorldwithNana) on YouTube and was able to create the configurations from the video. I have created a NATS service on a minicube from HELM repository as described in the [NATS documentation](https://docs.nats.io/running-a-nats-service/nats-kubernetes). I am able to run it, send and receive a subject, I was also able to configure Jetstream and I was able to receive the saved messages in the subjects via the consumer I created.
So far so good, I have a working NATS service, but I can't figure out how to access it from within or outside the cluster. I tried to access it by creating a load balancer, but I noticed that the cluster IP of the NATS service was missing.
I'm probably missing something fundamental, but my lack of experience prevents me from seeing it.

I would be very grateful if someone could help me access the service.